# What's the diffrence between \xFF and 0xFF

Tags: c, hex

1st - What's the difference between

```
#define s 0xFF
```

and

```
#define s '\xFF'
```

2nd - Why the second line equals to -1? 
3rd - Why after I try this (in the case of '\xFF')

```
unsigned char t = s;
putchar(t);
unsigned int p = s;
printf("\n%d\n", p);
```

the output is

```
(blank)
-1
```

?

thanks:)

Comment: What is x? How is it defined?

Comment: My mistake. Fixed! tnks:)

Comment: tnks gio! about the 2nd - let me check it out

Comment: But when the char is unsigned isn't supposed to be 255?

Comment: @HansPassant I just deleted my answer after "Vlad from Moscow" reminded me that `'\xFF' is an integer character constant and has type int.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This

```
#define s 0xFF
```

is a definition of hexadecimal integer constant. It has type `int` and its value is 255 in decimal notation.

This

```
#define s '\xFF'
```

is a definition of integer character constant that represented by a hexadecimal escape sequence. It also has type `int` but it represents a character. Its value is calculated differently.

According to the C Standard (p.#10 of section 6.4.4.4 Character constants)

> ...If an integer character constant contains a single character or
>   escape sequence, its value is the one that results when an object with
>   type char whose value is that of the single character or escape
>   sequence is converted to type int.

It seems that by default your compiler considers values of type char as values of type **signed char**. So according to the quote integer character constant
'\xFF' has negative value because the sign bit (MSB) is set and is equal to -1.

If you set the option of the compiler that controls whether type char is considered as signed or unsigned  to unsigned char then '\xFF' and 0xFF will have the same value that is 255.

Take into account that hexadecimal escape sequences may be used in string literals along with any other escape sequences.

Comment: The culprit here is the implementation-defined signedness of the default `char` type. Try using `uint8_t` instead and then the output will always be as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `'\xFF'` in a [string literal](http://ideone.com/WqnK5P) as last character and also as middle character using string concatenation but same is not true for `0xFF`.

Difference between `'\xFF'` and `0xFF` is analogous to difference between `'a'` and code of character `'a'` (Let's assume it is `0x61` for some implementation) with only difference `'\xFF'` will consume further hex characters if used in string.

---

When you print the character `FF` using putchar, output is implementation dependent. But when you print it as an integer, due to default promotion rule of varargs, it may print `-1` or `255` on systems where `char` behaves as `signed char` and `unsigned char` respectively.